Generalization of relation
There are 2 relations:
$$\sum _{r=0}^{\infty } \text{Li}_{-2 (r+1)}\left(-e^{-2 \pi }\right) \sum _{i=0}^{r-1} \frac{(-1)^i \pi ^{2 i} \zeta _{-2 i+2 r+2} \zeta _{-2 i+2 r+1}}{(2 i+1)!}=\frac{1}{48}-\frac{1}{16 \pi }$$
$$\sum _{r=0}^{\infty } \text{Li}_{-2 (r+1)}\left(e^{-\sqrt{3} \pi }\right) \sum _{i=0}^{r-1} \frac{(-1)^i \pi ^{2 i} \zeta _{-2 i+2 r+2} \zeta _{-2 i+2 r+1}}{(2 i+1)!}=\frac{1}{48}-\frac{1}{8 \sqrt{3} \pi }$$
Lets consider the following:
$$\sum _{r=0}^{\infty } \text{Li}_{-2 (r+1)}\left(\alpha_s e^{-s \pi }\right) \sum _{i=0}^{r-1} \frac{(-1)^i \pi ^{2 i} \zeta _{-2 i+2 r+2} \zeta _{-2 i+2 r+1}}{(2 i+1)!}=\frac{1}{48}-\frac{1}{8 \pi s }$$
where $\alpha_s$ is a const ($\alpha_2=-1$, $\alpha_\sqrt{3}=1$).
I can not find any other $\alpha_s$ except the above ones ($2$ and  $\sqrt{3}$). Any ideas are appreciated.
